# How to recover a previous draft?

Tags: craft3

I pasted in incorrect copy in my product description window in the dashboard, then updated the entry. Is there a way to find/revert to my previous draft? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your Entry click on the revision list next to the entry title.  [image]

Comment: Thanks very much! Hiding in plain sight.